# Encoding problems in Mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, unicode, mysql-connector

I have a table in a Mysql 5.1 schema. Statement for create this table is:

```
CREATE TABLE `prova` (

  `id` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`)

) ENGINE=InnoDb DEFAULT CHARSET=ucs2;
```

I have also a Java application, running on Ubuntu 10.10, that writes records in this table interfaced by Connector/J 5.1.14. Inserting records is done with Prepared Statement class.

When inserting a couple of records that differ for a marked char (e.g. ('aki kaurismäki','aki kaurismäki') and ('aki kaurismaki','aki kaurismaki')) I get a Duplicate key exception on second record. I tried to print query in the PreparedStatement before execution and it seems to be correct (I tried to execute this query manually from mysql command line client and get any error).

How could I solve this problem?
Thanks in advance,
Antonio

Comment: This is probably because `ucs2` normalizes accented characters internally in comparisons, leading to `kaurismäki` = `kaurismaki`. I don't know whether there is a 16-bit alternative character set that does not show this behaviour

Comment: Related: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-unicode-sets.html

Comment: Thanks for reply Pekka
It does work neither with utf8_general_ci nor with utf_unicode_ci.
It's really strange that same queries inserted in mysql command line client give no error..

Comment: no, those two collations work like the ucs2 one, they can't fix this. Try ucs2_bin as suggested below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because - as said in the comment - mySQL's Unicode encodings normalize accented characters internally in comparisons, leading to

```
 kaurismäki = kaurismaki
```

from the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-unicode-sets.html):

> To further illustrate, the following
>   equalities hold in both
>   utf8_general_ci and utf8_unicode_ci
>   (for the effect this has in
>   comparisons or when doing searches,
>   see Section 9.1.7.8, “Examples of the
>   Effect of Collation”):
>
> ```
> Ä = A 
> Ö = O 
> Ü = U
> ```

in my understanding, making the index column `ucs2_bin` should sort it out. A binary comparison will not normalize accented characters.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because the [collation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-charsets.html) is set to compare characters the same if they are accented, or even just different case (upper vs. lower case). What you probably need to do is set the collation to binary if you want accented characters to be compared in this way.  The downside of this is that it will also be case sensitive, which may or may not be what you want.  I don't think there's a collation for accent sensitive, but not case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is this related to the Collation of the table?

Examples of the Effect of Collation
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-collation-effect.html

Connection Character Sets and Collations
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html